# NodeJS install on Ubuntu

Tags: curl

I've just installed NodeJS on my Ubuntu, followihg the instructions from Node site. All went ok, but I am kind of confused by what I have actually done.

I enterred the following two commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

The second one is clear to me.
What does the first command do?

Comment: What about the first line is unclear? What the `curl` command does? What the `sudo` command does? What the `bash` command does? What the pipe`|` does? Something else? A mix?

Comment: a mix. What is result of the first line?

Comment: To say simple, `sudo -E bash` changes your Terminal (Bash) to `root` user.  And Execute the cURL output in BASH. Some Programmer Dude answer is Recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cURL](https://curl.haxx.se) is a command-line tool to transfer data using URLs. In this case it is making a request for `https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x`.

The `-L` option (if you read [the `curl` manual page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)) means that if the server responds with a redirect, `curl` will try with the new location.

The `-s` option means that `curl` should be silent, and not print errors or progress or other informational messages.

The data `curl` receives is printed on standard output.

This output is then *piped* into the input for the `sudo -E bash -` command. The [`sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) command runs the specified command as the superuser `root`. The option `-E` tells `sudo` to preserve the environment (e.g. the `$PATH` environment variable etc.).

The command that `sudo` runs is `bash -`, which is the standard Linux shell. The trailing dash (`-`) tells Bash that it should run as a login shell. The `bash` command will read its standard input and execute it as normal shell commands.

So what the whole line does, is simply do download a shell-script from `https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x` and use it as input for a shell to execute with superuser privileges.

Comment: Thank you, very clear answer. So, shis shell is probably kind of preparing the environment for the NodeJS setup. Is this right?

Do you, by coincidence, know, why this first step is needed in the context of NodeJS install? Shoudn't apt-get alone be able to finish the installation?

Comment: @Aleks The shell script is most likely adding special sources for `apt-get` so it can get the specified version of node. Among other things.

Answer (score 0):

***Simple solution:***

```
**FOR NODE VERSSION - 8.0.0 +**

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

**FOR NODE VERSSION - 10.0.0 +**

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```